# Debugging Rust with GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb, rust

I'm aware of the *debugging Rust* questions here on Stack Overflow and I also used GDB before with Go. However, I'm running into a problem where it seems GDB is unable to locate the debug symbols.

Consider this complex program in `main.rs`:

```
pub fn main () {
    println!("run");
}
```

I compile it with debug symbols

```
rustc -g main.rs
```

Then I run GDB

```
gdb main
```

This gives the first clue that something with the loading of debug symbols is not quite right.

[image: GDB: can't open to read error]

Now when I'm in GDB and type

```
list
```

it leaves me with some C code which isn't what I expect.

[image: screenshot of gdb list showing C code]

What am I doing wrong? My GDB version is 7.7 and I'm on OS X 10.9.2 (13C64). My rustc version is rustc 0.11.0-pre (3035d8dfb13077e195eb056568183911c90c1b4b 2014-07-02 21:26:40 +0000).

It may also be helpful to see the output of `gdb --configuration`:

```
This GDB was configured as follows:
    configure --host=x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 --target=x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
              --with-auto-load-dir=:${prefix}/share/auto-load
              --with-auto-load-safe-path=:${prefix}/share/auto-load
              --with-expat
              --with-gdb-datadir=/usr/local/share/gdb (relocatable)
              --with-jit-reader-dir=/usr/local/lib/gdb (relocatable)
              --without-libunwind-ia64
              --without-lzma
              --with-python=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
              --with-separate-debug-dir=/usr/local/lib/debug (relocatable)
              --with-zlib
              --without-babeltrace
```

Comment: Can’t reproduce on Arch Linux.

Comment: Which version or rust are you using?

Comment: I'm on `rustc 0.11.0-pre (3035d8dfb13077e195eb056568183911c90c1b4b 2014-07-02 21:26:40 +0000)`

Comment: Hm, this might be [#15567](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15567); could you try the `-g -C llvm-args="-dwarf-version 4"` workaround suggested there?

Comment: Nope, doesn't change anything for me. But what about */Users/cburgdorf/Documents/hacking/rust-playground/main.o* it seems it's trying to load symbols from `main.o` which does not exist? Or is it only trying to do that as a second attempt because it can't find them in the `main` binary?

Comment: Are you using some customized .gdbinit file? In that if you have set some source code path, then this scenario may appear.

Comment: @MantoshKumar nope. I posted the output of `gdb --configuration`. Does this contain anything helpful?

Comment: Ok, figured out what was wrong. See my own answer. Thank everyone for your help. I just wonder: As nobody pointed it out, is the `-g` parameter actually supposed to handle all that by itself?

Answer (score 14):

Same question, later Rust version (1.0.0-beta), totally different answer:

In GDB, when debugging a Rust executable, `break main` sets a breakpoint in some setup code that is part of the Rust standard library. This isn't what you want.

Instead type: `break $YOUR_CRATE::main`, substituting the name of your program for `$YOUR_CRATE`.

Comment: Thanks to "jshs" on the #rust IRC channel for this bit of wisdom.

Comment: Note that newer versions of Rust [include a hash in the method name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38416539/155423).

Comment: You can also use the `start` command in gdb, which is like "break main ; run" -- but it stops at the user-provided main program instead.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I figured out what was wrong. I have to manually emit the `main.o` file. I thought the `-g` parameter would just cut it.

Now that I run

```
rustc -g main.rs --emit="obj,link"
```

I can run

```
gdb main
```

And everything works like a charme.

I created two aliases for my bash to make things simple:

```
alias rd='rustc -g --emit="obj,link"'

compile_and_run() {
     rustc -g --emit="obj,link" $1 && gdb ${1%.*}
}

alias rdr=compile_and_run
```

Now I can just call `rdr main.rs` and it will start debugging `main.rs` with gdb.

Comment: I have no .o file on arch linux and it works (rust master, gdb 7.7.1)