# Unable to set a breakpoint on main while debugging a program compiled with Rust 1.10 with GDB

Tags: gdb, rust

I'm trying to step through this:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello {}", 0);
}
```

I've tried compiling with both: `cargo build` and `rustc -g -L src/main.rs`

I then run `gdb target/debug/rust-gdb-test` (or `gdb main`), and try to set a breakpoint on `main` with `break main`.

(`break ::rust-gdb-test::main` returns `Function "::rust-gdb-test" not defined.`).

After breaking (`Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555559610 in main ()`) if I try to run `list`, I get:

```
1   dl-debug.c: No such file or directory.
```

I am running Rust 1.10.0 `(cfcb716cf 2016-07-03)` and GDB 7.7.1 `(Debian 7.7.1+dfsg-5)`.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664994/debugging-rust-with-gdb) was asked 2 years ago, but I couldn't make the solutions presented there to work.

Comment: In gdb, if you use the `start` command, it will stop at the first line of the Rust main program, as opposed to the Rust-provided "bootstrap main".

Answer (score 3):

Note: I seem to not have GDB installed anymore, only LLDB, but for this question the answer is the same.

The `main` that you see in Rust is not the same `main` that exists in the compiled binary. Specifically, there are a number of shim methods between the two. The Rust `main` actually includes the crate name (in my example `buggin`) and a hash (in my case `hfe08615ed561bb88`):

```
  * frame #0: 0x000000010000126d buggin`buggin::main::hfe08615ed561bb88 + 29 at main.rs:2
    frame #1: 0x000000010000810e buggin`std::panicking::try::call::hbbf4746cba890ca7 + 30
    frame #2: 0x000000010000aadc buggin`__rust_try + 12
    frame #3: 0x000000010000aa76 buggin`__rust_maybe_catch_panic + 38
    frame #4: 0x0000000100007f32 buggin`std::rt::lang_start::hbcefdc316c2fbd45 + 562
    frame #5: 0x00000001000013aa buggin`main + 42
    frame #6: 0x00007fff910435ad libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #7: 0x00007fff910435ad libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Here, you can see that `main` is a few frames away in the stack.

I tend to use a wildcard breakpoint to not deal with the hash:

```
(lldb) br set -r 'buggin::main.*'
Breakpoint 5: where = buggin`buggin::main::hfe08615ed561bb88 + 29, address = 0x000000010000126d
```

`rbreak` should be an equivalent in GDB.

Once the program is stopped, you should be able to see the source. You may also be interested in the `rust-lldb` and `rust-gdb` wrappers that ship with Rust and improve the experience a bit.

This is basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29901831/155423), but mentions the hash.

> Neither `(gdb) rbreak 'rust-gdb-test::main.*'` nor `(lldb) br set -r 'rust-gdb-test::main.*'` set any breakpoints for me.

The hyphen (`-`) is not a valid symbol character. When compiled, it is converted to an underscore.

My original methodology was actually this:

```
(lldb) br set -r '.*main.*'
Breakpoint 2: 67 locations.
```

You can then run the program and continue a few times until you find the right place. Don't be afraid to get in there and explore a bit; it's just a debugger!

You could try various versions of the regex to see if anything interesting might match:

```
(lldb) br set -r '.*main::.*'
Breakpoint 3: where = rust-gdb-test`rust_gdb_test::main::h97d2ac6fea75a245 + 29,
(lldb) br set -r '.*::main.*'
Breakpoint 4: where = rust-gdb-test`rust_gdb_test::main::h97d2ac6fea75a245 + 29,
```

You could also call a function with a very unique name from `main` and set a breakpoint on that:

```
(lldb) br set -r '.*a_really_unique_name.*'
```

Comment: Neither `(gdb) rbreak 'rust-gdb-test::main.*'` nor `(lldb) br set -r 'rust-gdb-test::main.*'` set any breakpoints for me.